# Question marks in my kali linux shell

Tags: command-line, kali-linux, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to do active reconnaissance in Kali Linux (4.19.0-kali3-amd64) using `xprobe2` tool.

So I typed the command `xprobe2 espn.com` (for example).

I know that espn.com use "OpenBSD" server, then `xprobe2` must return something like:

```
[+] Host 13.249.184.80 Running OS: "OpenBSD 3.5" (Guess probability: 91%)
[+] Host 13.249.184.80 Running OS: "OpenBSD 3.7" (Guess probability: 93%)
```

But instead, it returned some white question marks in a black diamonds, in this form:

```
[+] Host 13.249.184.80 Running OS: � � � (Guess probability: 91%)
[+] Host 13.249.184.80 Running OS: � � � (Guess probability: 93%)
```

Note that I am using Unicode-UTF8 encoding in my shell script.

Why do I get question marks? (Even I get question marks when testing other sites)

Comment: FYI: Portscanning without permission can be treated as a crime - be careful.

Comment: I would expect espn.com (a) to be behind a strong firewall (b) to be using some form of load balancing front-end. Either way, you're unlikely to be able to hit anything of value